# On button click, selecting a random object from an array, and adding that item to a list using React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, state

ADDED AN EDIT AND UPDATED CODE WITH ITALICS - I managed to figure out how to do what I needed. I setArray(randomName.name) which updated the state arrayList to randomName.name - i could then inject this state with {arrayList} in my list component.

So the next thing I need to do, is add each subsequent click to a new List element I have no thoughts on how to do this, any tips appreciated.

**The array I am selecting from is in a local file called nameArray.**

```
export const nameArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Folly",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Leaf Blight",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Caesura",
  }];
  
**The NameButton component in another file**

function NameButton({ onClick, className, text }) {return (<button onClick={onClick} className={className}>
  {text}
</button> )};




**The smart component that handles the event of onlick passed up by NameButton**

function App() {
    const [arrayList, setArray] = useState([]);
    
  function handleClick() {
  
  const randomName =  nameArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * nameArray.length)] 
  console.log(randomName)  
  setArray(randomName.*name*)
      }
     
         

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Heading></Heading>
      <NameButton className="name-button" onClick={handleClick} text={"Generate Name"}></NameButton>
        <List> *text={arrayList}* **THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE RANDOM ITEM TO GO** </List>               
 )
};

export default App;

**This then gets rendered in my index.js at top level of directory**

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

The most I can get is for the random item from the nameArray to appear in the console.log - one weird thing is that the state of arrayList doesnt update to the randomName straight away, a second click will update the arraylist state to the first randomName generated and it continues like that, arrayList being updated to the previous randomName. I only include this as it is a bug that may offer some insight into the flow of my code, I am not sure why it does this.
I am completely lost, any advice appreciated.
If I need to include anything else, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is you get a single value from array. You should spread the result. So it should look like:
setArray([...arrayList, randomName])

- Because you declared that you expect array in that state.
  That array should be mapped with some key, and since the values won't be unique you can use index as a key.